# Stream on List to get element and also from inner elements

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a `List` of Employee object populated from a Json.

```
{
  "emp": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "id": "123",
      "reportingEmp": [
        {
          "name": "Mark",
          "id": "342"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike",
          "id": "342"
        },
        {
          "name": "Lindsey",
          "id": "342"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "id": "123"
    },
    {
      "name": "Andrew",
      "id": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
class Employee {
private String name;
private String id;
private List<Employee> reportingEmp;
}
```

Now I wanted to get the names of all employess including the reporting employees in a stream.

I can use the below to get all the employees but it would miss the reporting employees

`List<String> names = emp.stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(toList());`

But the above would give only `John,Steve and Andrew` but I want the below list

```
John
Mark
Mike
Lindsey
Steve
Andrew
```

Comment: What if the reporting employees also have reporting employees? Do you also want those as well?

Comment: @Sweeper Reporting employees will not have reporting employess

Comment: `employees.stream().collect(ArrayList::new, (names, employee) -> {
                            if (employee.getReportingEmp() != null) names.addAll(employee.getReportingEmp().stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));names.add(employee.getName());},
                        ArrayList::addAll);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) is the thing to use, when you want to map one thing (an `Employee`) to multiple things (the employee's name + all the reporting employees' names).

In the `flatMap` lambda, you just need to create a stream that contains the things you want to map that employee to, so:

```
List<String> names = employees.stream().flatMap(emp ->
    Stream.concat(
        // the employee's name,
        Stream.of(emp.getName()), // and
        // the employee's reporting employees' names
        emp.getReportingEmp().stream().map(Employee::getName)
    )
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `getReportingEmp` can return `null`, then you can do:

```
List<String> names = employees.stream().flatMap(emp ->
    Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(emp.getName()),
        Optional.ofNullable(emp.getReportingEmp()).map(
            x -> x.stream().map(Employee::getName)
        ).orElse(Stream.of())
    )
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: worth mentioning that `emp.getReportingEmp()` seems optional, one might have to update the implementation based on that

Comment: Yes, it could be looking at the JSON.